# Return rows that match a larger partial string of a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like the following:

```
Type      Size
Biomass   12
Coal      15
Nuclear   23
```

And I have a string `str` such as the following: `Biomass_wood`
I would like to return the following dataframe:

```
Type      Size
Biomass   12
```

This is because `Biomass` is partially matched by the first part of `Biomass_wood`.

This would effectively be the opposite of `df[df.Type.str.contains(str)]` as the bigger string is contained in `str` and not in the column `Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do

```
df[df['Type'].map(lambda t: t in 'Biomass_wood')]
```

Comment: This is a bad answer to an obvious duplicate question.

Comment: Are you sure it's a duplicate? The OP clearly states that `df[df.Type.str.contains(str)]` is the opposite of what they need.

Comment: Oh, right... so maybe not a duplicate of that, but I've definitely seen this before.

Comment: Thank you ayorgo, this worked well.